# Does parallel transport apply to points or vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

My current understanding of parallel transport is the following:

Let $P \xrightarrow{\pi} M$ be a principal $G$-bundle and $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow M$ a curve in $M$. For a given connection $A$, we may define a map
$$\Pi_\gamma^A: P_{\gamma(a)} \rightarrow P_{\gamma(b)}\\
p \mapsto \gamma_p^*(b)$$
where $\gamma^*_p$ is the horizontal lift of $\gamma$ such that $\gamma^*_p(a) = p$.

Thus we see that parallel transport is a way to map a point in one fiber to another, hence it maps points in $P$ to points in $P$.

What has been confusing me is that many resources, such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) or [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelTransport.html), instead describe parallel transport as transporting vectors. I do not see how the above definition of parallel transport has anything to do with vectors unless we consider $(\Pi_\gamma^A)_*$, the pushforward of the parallel transport map, but this is never mentioned.

What is the connection between these two viewpoints?

Comment: Given a representation $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ you can consider the associated bundle with fiber $V$ and then parallel transport gives maps between the fibers of the associated bundle, which are copies of $V$ and hence which consist of vectors. The motivating example is the Levi-Civita connection on the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: It better act on vectors (more generally fibers) and not just points in the base space, otherwise holonomy would be a rather trivial concept.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you, so the vectors that we are transporting come from the vector space which we use to construct the associated vector bundle, and have nothing to do with tangent vectors? In other words, are people actually referring to parallel transport in the associated vector bundle? I guess I had incorrectly assumed that the vectors being transported were always tangent vectors to the total space because of the visualizations one often sees (e.g. the image on Wikipedia where a vector is being sent across a curve along a sphere)

Comment: @CBBAM: well, if the principal bundle you consider is the frame bundle, then of course you recover the tangent bundle as an associated bundle, so the general construction above has the tangent bundle as a special case. It's a very important special case so that's why it's the one you see discussed first and most often.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan This finally makes a lot a sense, thank you very much!

Comment: Just to be explicit, the distinction between _points_ and _vectors_ out of context is the source of ambiguity: A _point_ of a frame bundle determines _a bunch of vectors_ at a point of the base manifold.

Comment: Now you know why books typically write points in $P$ as $\xi$ rather than $p$. We are used to thinking of $p$ as a point in a manifold, and a point of $P$ is typically a frame.